# JSONKIT objectFromJSON double value parsing error

Tags: json, double

When I try to parse a JSON string like this with `objectFromJson:

```
{
"idvino": 2,
"idusuario": 2,
"notamedia": 0.0,
"numerovotaciones": 0,
"usuario": null,
"nombre": "Romanico",
"comentariocata": null,
"rutaimagen": "media/vinos/defecto.jpg",
"bodega": "",
"fechaalta": "2013-01-22",
"anio": "2009",
"barcode": "",
"pais": "España",
"tipovino": "Tinto",
"variedad": "Tempranillo",
"zona": "Ribera del Duero",
"status": "NoVerificado"
}
```

The result is an `NSDictionary` with the value `"notamedia": 0` but in the JSON string it's "`notamedia": 3.3`

Why do I have this result in the `NSDictionary`?

Comment: In the JSON you posted, `notamedia` corresponds to the value `0.0`.

Comment: Yes, but in the NSDictionary the value is 0 not 0.0, why?

Comment: Perhaps because `0.0` is the same as `0`? Or what kind of weird number system are you using, if it isn't?

Comment: In another json I have " notamedia":3.3 but in the nsdictionary I have notamedia:3